# How to store array data in MySQL database using PHP & MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php and mysql and I'm trying to learn how to store the following array data from three different arrays `friend[], hair_type[], hair_color[]` using MySQL and PHP an example would be nice. Thanks

Here is the HTML code.

```
<input type="text" name="friend[]" id="friend[]" />

<select id="hair_type[]" name="hair_type[]">
    <option value="Hair Type" selected="selected">Hair Type</option>
    <option value="Straight">Straight</option>
    <option value="Curly">Curly</option>
    <option value="Wavey">Wavey</option>
    <option value="Bald">Bald</option>
</select>

<select id="hair_color[]" name="hair_color[]">
    <option value="Hair Color" selected="selected">Hair Color</option>
    <option value="Brown">Brown</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blonde">Blonde</option>
</select>





<input type="text" name="friend[]" id="friend[]" />

<select id="hair_type[]" name="hair_type[]">
    <option value="Hair Type" selected="selected">Hair Type</option>
    <option value="Straight">Straight</option>
    <option value="Curly">Curly</option>
    <option value="Wavey">Wavey</option>
    <option value="Bald">Bald</option>
</select>

<select id="hair_color[]" name="hair_color[]">
    <option value="Hair Color" selected="selected">Hair Color</option>
    <option value="Brown">Brown</option>
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blonde">Blonde</option>
</select>
```

Here is the MySQL tables below.

```
CREATE TABLE friends_hair (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
hair_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE hair_types (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
friend TEXT NOT NULL,
hair_type TEXT NOT NULL,
hair_color TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: Are you trying to store the options for each select, or the results from the form, or both?

Comment: I'm trying to store the results from the user.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table for hair type, hair color, and friend.

Hair type and hair color each need a primary key of `id`, and a `name` field.

Friend needs a primary key of `id`, and fields of `name`, `hair_type_id`, and `hair_color_id`.

Make the values for hair type and hair color their respective id from the database.

When you submit the form, loop through the $_POST['friend'] array, insert into the friend database the friend name, hair type id, and hair color id.

Don't forget to sanitize the inputs. Check out [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for an example of that.

I can make this more detailed if you need further help.

Comment: whats the problem with my table? and you lost me.

Comment: I'm making the assumption that friends are the data you're interested in, with hair types and hair colors being just lists types that won't change often. With my method, you can have those lists in their own table, easy to add to if you need to, and then the friends table will relate each friend name to their hair color and type. If that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you can only have one hair type and one hair colour per user then check the pastie for a simple answer: http://pastie.org/928039

let's face it you can't have wavey and straight hair at the same time now can you ? Colours might be different in which case it's a many to many so you need a user_hair_colour table user_hair_colour(user_id PK, hair_colour_id PK) :P

```
 select 
   u.*,
   hc.name as hair_colour_name,
   ht.name as hair_type_name
 from 
  users u
 inner join hair_colour hc on u.hair_colour_id = hc.hair_colour_id 
 inner join hair_type ht on u.hair_type_id = ht.hair_type_id 
 order by 
  u.username;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Serialise function to store the array into mysql database, and to retrieve the values use Unserialise function..
[PHP serialize function](https://www.php.net/serialize)